# ¿Cómo puedo castear en una consulta un texto extraido de una columna en una base de datos SQLIte a entero?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Estoy usando SQLite 3 y tengo una tabla que tiene una columna donde guardo los datos de un objeto serializado con json, la columna se llama json y su contenido puede ser algo como esto

```
{"Equip":{"Name":"Freezer","Cost":300,"Start_Date":"15/08/2017","Count":2,"Life_Time":5,"Active":1,"Id":1},"Count":2,"Cost":1125,"Is_Repair":0}
```

Lo que necesito es hacer una consulta para sumar los valores Count almacenados dentro de esta columna seria algo como esto

```
select SUM(CAST(substring(json,instr('Count":',json)+5,instr(',"Is_Repair":',json)-(instr('Count":',json)+5)), 'INTEGER')) as TOTAL from trace
```

No es que existan esas funciones realmente es mas o menos como lo haria si existiera una función llamada CAST(obj,tipo) donde **obj** es lo que quiero castear y **tipo** es a lo que lo quiero convertir.
Otra función llamada instr(substr,texto) que busca en texto una coincidencia para la subcadena "substr" y si la encuentra devuelve la posición en la que la encontró osea algo bastante parecido a String.IndexOf en c#.

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, el json que se guarda siempre tiene la misma estructura?

Comment: Utilizo la clase Newtonsoft.Json.Convert para serializar el objeto que guardo en la columna de la tabla, y si, la estructura se mantiene lo que los datos de las propiedades varian en algunos casos.